# send particular log file from rsyslog client host to remote rsyslog server

Tags: rsyslog

I need to send ONLY  jboss.log logfile to remote rsyslog server
/var/log/jboss/jboss.log
Can smbd provide me simple configs on client and server side to do that?
Thank you

PS reading similar questions now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before asking future questions, please make sure that you've exhausted all ressources and read possible *similar questions* before asking. For more tips, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Rsyslog is a system for forwarding/processing log **messages**. It is **not** able to send entire files. To send *log* (or any other) files you can use e.g. [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) or [scp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp).

This will send a single file:

```
rsync -vz --progress /path/to/file.txt username@<remote-ip>:/path/to/some/dir/
```